# Filtered data copy is saving to sheet 2 in new workbook

Tags: vba

I have set up code to copy a filtered table into a new document, it works fine but for some reason the data ends up in Sheet 2 of the new workbook. Could someone please enlighten me as to why? I cant see any reference to sheet 2 so am very confused (also very much a novice)

Here is the code I use:

```vb
Sub CopyFilteredTable()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

    For Each Row In Range("Table2[#All]").Rows
        If Row.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = Row
            Set rng = Union(Row, rng)
        End If
    Next Row

    Set WS = Sheets.Add
    rng.Copy newBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove this line Set WS = Sheets.Add  and try.. Also you can modify rng.copy newbook.Worksheets(1).Range ("A1")

Comment: You legend- worked perfectly.

Comment: Posting this as an answer plz accept it, which will help others

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line Set WS = Sheets.Add and try..

Also you can modify line rng.Copy newBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") as `**rng.copy newbook.Worksheets(1).Range ("A1")**`